# Неправильно работает скрипт

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Возникла проблема, задача состоит в том, что при нажатии на ссылку должна отправляться форма и данные выводиться на экран, но скрипт выводит полностью заново сформированную страницу. В чем может быть проблема? Заранее спасибо.

```
jQuery(function(){
        // откуда берем данные сформы
        jQuery('.button-send').click(function(e){
            //отменяем стандартное действие при отправке формы
    // e.preventDefault();
            //берем из формы метод передачи данных
            var m_method=jQuery('#info-send').attr('method');
            //получаем адрес скрипта на сервере, куда нужно отправить форму
            var m_action=jQuery('#info-send').attr('action');
            //получаем данные, введенные пользователем в формате input1=value1&input2=value2...,
            //то есть в стандартном формате передачи данных формы
            var m_data=jQuery('#info-send').serialize();
    jQuery.ajax({
                type: m_method,
                url: m_action,
                data: m_data,
                success: function(result){
                    // где показываем результат
                    jQuery('#result').html(result);
                }
        });
    });
});
```

**Обновление**

Нет, дело не в этом, все так и должно быть, смысл в том, что если вместо

```
jQuery('#result').html(result);
```

вывести

```
jQuery('#result').html('123');
```

то все прекрасно работает.

Answer (score 1):

То есть вы желаете не отправлять форму обычным способом, но при это не делаете "return false" и даже не перехватываете событие submit?. Почитайте http://jquery-docs.ru/events/submit/  просветление как вам придет)).

Для справки: Функция jQuery() является, пожалуй, основной функцией в библиотеке. Она обычно вызывается намного чаще других, и поэтому для нее существует короткая форма записи — $().(с рунета)  Ото как-то в глаза сразу бросается.

Comment: Действие должно происходить не с помощью кнопки отправки формы, а с помощью кнопки открытия модального окна, кнопка sumbit уже внутри этого окна. В этом окне должна вывестись информация из БД. Сайт основан на джумле, и ошибку выдает при попытки законектить joomla framework.
скрипт брал отсюда http://www.cleverscript.ru/cms/joomla/54-kak-podkluchitsya-k-vneshney-baze-dannuh-v-joomla.html#.VHnikjGsUhA

P.S. краткая форма конфликтуют с чем-то, работает - не трогай.

Answer (score 0):

Исходя из представленных данных, попробуйте раскомментировать отмену действия отправки по умолчанию, "// e.preventDefault();" А если не поможет, то добавьте html-код в вопрос.

Comment: Обновил ворос

Answer (score 0):

Если данные в базе уже, то я бы редирект использовал бы для перехода на другую страницу и вывода там уже нужно информации. В таком случае весим код на событие onsumbit и без ajax все.